# Convert WriteableBitmap to BitmapImage using BmpBitmapEncoder WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap

I have a problem with Convert WriteableBitmap to BitmapImage using BmpBitmapEncoder.
this is my method:

```
    public BitmapImage ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(WriteableBitmap wbm)
    {
        bmp = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            /*PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);*/
            BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);

            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.UriSource = new Uri(MyImage.Source.ToString());
            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache | BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            bmp.StreamSource = stream;
            bmp.EndInit();
            bmp.Freeze();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

I'm using BmpBitmapEncoder because this is only way to Save without change size of Image(*.bmp). I want to Save Image with changed table of pixels and the specified format pixel (Bgr24). Using BmpBitmapEncoder forces to set bmp.UriSource and this is a problem. WriteableBitmap doesn't have this Property. Moreover, when I comment line //bmp.UriSource shows me an exception: "System.ArgumentNullException" in bmp.EndInit().
When I change my Method to this:

```
    public BitmapImage ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(WriteableBitmap wbm)
    {
        bmp = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            /*BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);*/

            bmp.BeginInit();
            //bmp.UriSource = new Uri(MyImage.Source.ToString());
            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            //bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache | BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            bmp.StreamSource = stream;
            bmp.EndInit();
            bmp.Freeze();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

everything works fine but the result is the Image increase size and change pixel format to Bgr32 and this is not the result, what I expect. My method which Save Image is fine because I tested it on unchanged pixels and the result is good - Image don't change format and size. Plz help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

For changing pixel formats WPF has the `FormatConvertedBitmap` class, which is a BitmapSource:

```
WriteableBitmap wbm;
...
var bm = new FormatConvertedBitmap(wbm, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, 0);
```

It is not a BitmapImage, but you do not really need that anywhere. All WPF  methods and properties (e.g. `Image.Source`) use either `ImageSource` or the derived `BitmapSource` as their type. There is no API that explicitly needs a BitmapImage, so conversion to BitmapImage is never necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem. This is a code which Convert WriteableBitmap to BitmapImage using BmpBitmapEncoder. Using this method ensure us, that our Image while saving stay unchanged. Unchanged I mean - size don't increase and Format Pixel stay on Bgr24.

```
    public BitmapImage ConvertWriteableBitmapToBitmapImage(WriteableBitmap wbm)
    {
        bmp = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wbm));
            encoder.Save(stream);
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            bmp.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()); //stream;
            bmp.EndInit();
            bmp.Freeze();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: You still haven't told us why you need a BitmapImage at all. The whole conversion is usually not necessary, because you can pass the original WriteableBitmap to all methods or properties that accept a BitmapSource or ImageSource.